# Relative QWidget position in parent - incorrect Y

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Maybe I'm just having a bad day but I just can't seem to get this to work.

I'm trying to set the position of a widget floating inside another but it always seems to be offset.

My layout looks like this and I'm trying to make a "floating" widget inside `canvas` in the top right.

[image]

I re-implemented the `show` method (have also tried the `showEvent`) with this logic:

```
def show(self):
    pos = self.parent().mapToGlobal(self.parent().pos())
    topright = self.parent().rect().topRight()
    self.resize(QSize(self.geometry().width(), self.parent().geometry().size().height()))
    newpos = (pos + topright) - QPoint(self.geometry().width(), 0)
    self.move(newpos)
    super(InfoDock, self).show()
```

This is the result:

[image]

The two toolbars are added into `canvas_page` using:

```
self.canvas_page.layout().insertWidget(2, self.toolbar2)
self.canvas_page.layout().insertWidget(3, self.toolbar)
```

If I remove these calls it moves the widget higher but it still seems to be offset the size of settignsLabel_2 and line_2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set an absolute (floating) position for a widget, reimplement the [resizeEvent](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#resizeEvent) of its parent, and [move()](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#pos-prop) the widget relative to that parent:

```
def resizeEvent(self, event):
    # move to top-right corner
    self.widget.move(self.width() - self.widget.width() - 1, 1)
    super(Canvas, self).resizeEvent(event)
```

**UPDATE**:

Working demo script:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        toolbar = self.addToolBar('Toolbar')
        toolbar.addAction('Action')
        widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        self.canvas = Canvas(widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

class Canvas(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Canvas, self).__init__(parent)
        self.widget = QtGui.QComboBox(self)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.widget.move(self.width() - self.widget.width() - 2, 2)
        super(Canvas, self).resizeEvent(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 200, 200)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.  Would Canvas being a QGraphicsView have anything to do with it?

Comment: @NathanW. I've added a little demo script that works for me, but obviously it overlooks a lot of the details of your particular case. When and how do you create the InfoDock widget, and what is its parent?

Comment: Thanks.  That was my mistake.  I was using Qt.Tool in the flags and it was messing it up.